# How to fix include_external_user_ids error in OneSignal

Tags: onesignal

i setup Mobile Pust notificatio with OneSignal, 
i following two step to do this but it not working

1. In App.js, i wrote :

   ```
   OneSignal.init("xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"); 
   OneSignal.setExternalUserId('my user_id');
   ```
2. In my backend :

   ```
   $fields = array(
       'app_id' => ONESIGNAL_APP_ID,
       'include_external_user_ids' => array('my user_id'),
       'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
       'contents' => $content
   );
   ```

But it not worked for me. Can u help me

Comment: did you find its solution?